# how do I search within a CSS file for specific class in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I am using a bootstrap template for a webpage. I want to customise certain parts of it, but I am struggling to find the CSS rules that relate to the HTML classes because the .css file is so large!

All I can find when searching the web for a solution is ways to search for files rather than within them. It looks as if there was an extension that may have worked, but it doesn't seem to exist any longer.

any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can search over files in VS Code using CTRL/SHIFT/F, more info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files)

This is from the website:

VS Code allows you to quickly search over all files in the currently opened folder. Press Ctrl+Shift+F and enter your search term. Search results are grouped into files containing the search term, with an indication of the hits in each file and its location. Expand a file to see a preview of all of the hits within that file. Then single-click on one of the hits to view it in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

simple just "ctrl+f" and type whatever you want to search inside text box show on top right corner.

Comment: This. Can't believe it was this simple  thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to "find the CSS rules that relate to the HTML classes" is still to open your template/website in a browser -> right click the page and "Inspect Element" -> Find the HTML you need to inspect -> You'll have all the CSS classes and rules involved into styling it ...in the sub-tab "Styles".

Comment: the problem is finding the specific class in the huge amount of css. i know the name of the class, i just need an easy way to find it in the css file!

Comment: In that case you can " Ctrl+f " in your code editor from the Bootstrap page and fill in the .className your're looking for in the search field. The part you want to inspect will be highlited.